# Looking for a program to backup data (synchronization)

Tags: backup, windows-7-backup

I have Windows 7, I need a program to backup data from two partitions. I have a portable drive that I would like to make a copy of selected folders. Every month, update the backup (one-sided synchronization). What can you recommend? Thanks for help

Comment: I would recommend Amazon Glacier. Not really a program but a service. There are programs out there that will help with this.

Answer (score 0):

This must have been answered before but I can't find it right now.

Solutions include rsync, unison or robocopy

Answer (score 0):

I use the freeware [Allway Sync](http://allwaysync.com/) to synchronize files on a thumb drive with folders on a hard drive whenever I plug in the thumb drive.  It's small and stable; I leave it running all the time with no issues.  It can also be used with the Windows Scheduler, and there's a lot of flexibility in how synchronization works.